# What is the relationship between $\mathsf{APX}$ and $\mathsf{MaxSNP}$ classes?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, approximation-hardness

My understanding of these classes is a really fuzzy. The more I am trying to read the more I am getting confused. Can anyone help me understand the relationship between these classes. More precisely, is $\mathsf{MaxSNP} = \mathsf{APX}$  or $\mathsf{MaxSNP} \subset\mathsf{APX}$?

Thanks a lot in advance. :)

Comment: See the following paper by Khanna etal on syntactic vs computational views of approximability. MaxSNP is a syntactic class while APX is a computational class. http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=298507

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri comment -> answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following paper by Khanna etal on syntactic vs computational views of approximability. MaxSNP is a syntactic class while APX is a computational class. dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=298507

Made comment into answer as per Suresh's request.

Answer (score 0):

$MaxSNP=APX$. This is according to [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/APX)

Comment: That is interesting. In the Wikipedia article about $MaxSNP$ it says: "The closure of MaxSNP under PTAS reductions is APX."